# Open phpMyAdmin database on localhost:1234

Tags: phpmyadmin

I had to install my xampp to run on localhost:1234 tp prevent a conflict with skype. Now I don't know how to access the phpMyAdmin database. What is te right address to access phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have changed the port for apache to be 1234, not for mysql.
By default your mysql from xampp is at port 3306. If localhost:3306/phpmyadmin show not found, try https://localhost:3306/phpmyadmin. Or drop the port.